# How to publish all records in a meteor collection ... except one or two

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to publish all records in a Meteor collection except two. Let's say their document IDs are "abc" and "xyz." Does anyone know how to write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Meteor.publish("my_pub", function() {
  return Something.find({ _id: { $nin: ['abc', 'xyz'] }})
})
```